# remove caching data with 304 status

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have a React/Express application that manages appointments. Appointments are scheduled using a calendar displayed in a modal. The modal retrieves data from the database to disable unavailable dates on the calendar.

When an appointment is created, the modal closes. However, when it is reopened, a new request should be sent to the database to update the disabled dates, as shown in the useEffect hook:

```js
useEffect(() => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        axios
            .get('/api/reservations')
            .then((res) => {
                setReservations(res.data);
            })
            .catch((err) =>
                toast.error(err?.response?.data?.message || 'An error has occured')
            )
            .finally(() => {
                setIsLoading(false);
            });
    }, [reservationModal.isOpen]);
```

The issue here is that **whenever a reservation is made** and the modal is closed, when I open it again in order to make a new reservation, the request to the server is not made even though the data is modified (because I have just made a new reservation) and I get a **304 status code** and therefore the calendar is not updated (to disable the unavalaible dates).

Here's the api endpoint :

```js
app.get('/api/reservations', (req, res) => {
    db.query('SELECT * FROM reservation ORDER BY dateTime ASC', (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(Date() + ' /api/reservations ' + err);
            res
                .status(500)
                .send({ message: 'An error occured' });
        } else {
            console.log(result)
            res.status(200).send(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Is there any way to disable this data caching? Knowing that I have deployed this app on Cpanel. But when I run it locally I don't have this issue.